# Visualising high dimensional data

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

My data is of the form $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{20}\times\mathbb{R}$ where I denote the components of the independent variable $x=(x_1,...,x_{20})$. The $y$ variable is just a binary variable, $y\in\{0,1\}$.

The independent variable $x$ is quite abstract in my case. The components are continuous real values.

The $y$ variable is obtained by a one-class classification method.

Is there any useful way I can still try to visualize the data?
I thought of plotting only the projections onto two of the components and do this for every possibility, meaning plotting $(x_1,x_2,y), (x_1,x_3,y)...(x_{20},x_{19},y)$. This would yield $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ plots, where $n$ is the number of components. In our case, this would be $n=20$.

How can I do this in ggplot2? I could not get it to work using facet plotting.

EDIT: I transformed the data that I can now deal with real values, instead of nominal ones.

Comment: hey, it's do-able but 190 plots... a bit hard to visualize or even put on 1 single pdf?

Comment: I think this is a classical case of using dimensionality reduction to visualise a dataset.

Comment: ggpairs from the GGally package might help you if you really need to plot all of the data rather than use some dimension reduction technique first.

Comment: A [parallel coordinates chart](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/parallel-plot.html) that uses a graphical symbol (e.g., color, line weight, point shape) to distinguish the state of $y$ might work well.  What you choose ultimately ought to depend on what you want to use the chart for and who your intended audience is: could you elaborate?

Comment: @usεr11852saysReinstateMonic I know PCA and SOM's. Do you think this is applicable? I might have also been too specific in my example. Maybe a little bit more general formulation of my problem will help: Given high dimensional data, how can I visualize it, to be able to see groups or clusters or any pattern at all? First thing I do with data is usually to clean and visualize it, but I don't have any experience how to do this in high dimensions.

Comment: @whuber I don't think this is reasonable, since I have about 4000 datapoints and about 20 dimensions in $x$. As I wrote in my other comment, I want to be able to see if the data points are grouped, meaning what the support of the density looks like.

Comment: Why is it unreasonable?  20 dimensions can be visibly plotted on such a chart.